# No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' even on tensorflow 1.13.2

Tags: tensorflow, gpt-2

I cant import a gpt_2_simple package due to an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

I have installed python 3.7 and tried to install tensorflow 1.15.5, 1.15.2 and 1.13.2 and all of them were gaining this mistake. Im using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Works with python 3.6 and tensorflow 1.15.2